# How do can i display all test cases of TestNG upfront to choose some for execution - test explorer?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng, integration-testing

Is there an IDE / plugin for an IDE / other way to displays all test cases of an project upfront? And then select and execute them from that view. A test explorer.
I want to get an overview of all tests, the wohle suite, without executing all once. Like a dry run but, executable afterwards with no extra effort.
At best with all cases from data providers included to run specific cases.

I have yet tried Eclipse and Intellij with their plugins.

I'm a software tester developing automated system tests / integration tests. As this tests are running half an hour and more, i don't want to wait for their execution to end to get an overview.

Language is groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be an IDE or a plugin?
You can use a Listener to print or Report the tests on start:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

@Listeners(TestListener.class)
public class TestClass {

   @Test
   public void testMethodA() {
      /* Some testing here */
   }

}
```

---

```
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

        for (ITestNGMethod method : context.getAllTestMethods()) {
            System.out.println("Test: " + method.getMethodName());
            System.out.println("Description: " + method.getDescription());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    }

}
```

Of course the System.out is just for the example. You could do in there what you need with that information.

Comment: How could i start tests from that report interactively?
Ill update the question.

Comment: You can have a system parameter 'dryRun=true'. If TRUE, then you can run that code above filling a form with the tests that are about to be executed, but not executing them (terminating the process or something), and you can place them with check-boxes. You can have a task in that form to pick the checked tests and generate a new testng.xml and execute it.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but prefer built-in feature for an IDE like Eclipse or Intellij which i'm using to develop my test.
Both are having views for tests, but these are just displaying executed and not all existing tests.
Best so far is the Test Explorer from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for the ability to selectively run or debug tests from within Eclipse.

Yes, you need to first install TestNG add-in via 'Install new software' available under the 'Help' menu.

Once you have it installed, make the class file containing tests as active window. Then TestNG add-in gives you not only the ability to see all the tests but also let you select & run specific tests in an explorer like window as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: But just the one in the selected class? Not all of my project?
I'd like to have an overview over the whole project(s). Visual Studio's Text Explorer does this.
I have used Eclipse with that add-in.